# Can I configure Apache ActiveMQ to use the STOMP protocol over UDP?

Tags: udp, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm developing a STOMP binding for Ada, which is working fine utilizing TCP/IP as the transport between the client and an ActiveMQ server configured as a STOMP broker. I thought to support UDP as well (i.e. STOMP over UDP), however, the lack of pertinent information in the ActiveMQ documentation or in web searches suggests to me that this isn't possible, and perhaps it doesn't even make any sense :-)

Confirmation one way or the other (and an ActiveMQ configuration excerpt if this is possible) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not implemented in ActiveMQ at the moment as Stomp transport uses TCP only. It is possible to implement, so if you have a time to do it, give it a try.